# OnChange in input does not fire if mouse is not moving

Tags: javascript, html, input

Here is an example of code I have

```
<html>
<script>
function onKeyUpEstimatedHoursInput() {
  console.log("onKeyUpEstimatedHoursInput - 1");
}
function onKeyPressEstimatedHoursInput() {
  console.log("onKeyPressEstimatedHoursInput - 1");
}
function onChangeEstimatedHoursInput() {
  console.log("onChangeEstimatedHoursInput - 1");
}
</script>

<input type="number" onchange="onChangeEstimatedHoursInput();" onkeypress="onKeyPressEstimatedHoursInput();" onkeyup="onKeyUpEstimatedHoursInput();" step="0.01">
</html>
```

The problem is that if you click on 'increase value' or 'decrease value' button 
[image]

it fires only when you clicks it first time.
On screenshot I clicked 20 times. But moved mouse twice. The first time the code wrote to log and then first time after moving mouse.
Browsers - Chrome, Firefox (Win7).

Question: **How to get all the clicks?**

Comment: Works fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/k6yre5kv/

Comment: Good question. I think it is about updates of the events in the navigator.

Comment: @adeneo, doesn't work for me. I went through your link. The same situation. Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: @adeneo tried the fiddle on chrome on a mac, issue is as described in the post. jsfiddle site does not work at all for me on FF mac

Comment: For me it works perfectly fine in both Chrome and Firefox, but it does log the same thing every time. Maybe this makes it clearer -> https://jsfiddle.net/k6yre5kv/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it seems in Chrome some of the clicks do not generate the `change` event.  I could not reproduce it in FireFox.

But there is another event which does not need the focus to leave the input area: `input`. That will always trigger whatever the I/O means are to change the content of the input: up/down button, mouse drag/drop, keyboard, context menu, other unusual input devices...

```js
function onInput() {
  console.log("onInput");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="onInput();" step="0.01">
```

Comment: Freaking insane! When you put onInput in html - works fine in both C and FF. When assign with addEventListener - works only in FF.